# I have a script that changes an object to a broken version of itself when clicked, but it keeps rotating the object

Tags: c#, unity, rotation

So I have made a script in unity that you put on an object and when you click the object it will delete the object and replace it with a broken one I made in blender. My problem is that when I click the object and it deletes it, for some reason unity will take the broken object and rotate it 90 degrees. My only guesses of whats happening is, it's my code that is causing it or in my blender files when I bring them into unity some are flipped 90 degrees while others aren't. I would really appreciate any help anyone could give me. Also I will have a link to a video to demonstrate the problem better and I will include my code below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5NubLl-hLw

Thanks, Nova

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Destruction : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject destructionPiece;

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Instantiate (destructionPiece, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like it rotates 90 degrees, not 180. What happens when you drag the broken prefab into the scene? Is the rotated or as it should be?

Comment: Yeah when I put both objects into the scene there're both rotated to the angle they should be at (Which is parallel to the ground).

Comment: Ok... Have you tried printing the current rotation of the table in game and then do the same for the broken one and see what you come up with

Comment: No I haven't but I will try it and see what I get

Comment: Blender uses a different coordinate system than Unity which causes models to appear rotated when imported into Unity.

Comment: "when I put both objects into the scene there're both rotated to the angle they should be" - Can you show us a screengrab of this, including the inspector parameters on each one? There's a chance one of the prefabs has a 90-degree rotation set by default in its inspector, which makes it look correct when dragged in. When this is overwritten by / overwrites the other object's rotation during the model swap, you end up with a 90-degree mismatch.